# Insert, Update and Delete from a SQLite Database (Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I already have a SQLite Database setup which I am using as cache for the Android application. The application does a HTTP Request and gets back a List of objects which I can insert into the db. After the first request, if I do anymore requests, how do all of the following in a better way:

1) insert all new objects from the list
2) update all objects that were already in the db
3) delete all rows that were not there in the latest list of objects.

I know that options 1 and 2 can be done using the "INSERT OR UPDATE" query. How can I manage the 3rd option efficiently?

Right now my approach is to delete all from table and then insert all. But that isn't very efficient. Any ideas how to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use the ids of the rows. For doing that first retrieve all the rows which you want to delete using SELECT query and add it a temporary arraylist, then use for loop over the arraylist to delete all those rows by using DELETE query.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your operations using the applyBatch() method of the ContentProvider (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#applyBatch(java.util.ArrayList)).

You can perform this method in a separate thread asynchronously so that you do not block anything else. You will have to create a list of ContentProviderOperations. In fact, you only need to specify the ones you need to insert or update within the ArrayList and implement the applyBatch() method such that it will automatically delete the rest of the entries in the database.

To answer your question about how to delete the entries not in the table, the logical assumption would be to search through your data sequentially and then delete the ones that do not need to exist.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the intention is to refresh the Http request result set saved in the database. So I think the most efficient way is do a transaction or batch operation to delete all rows from the table first and then insert the new rows. A transaction might be better so that the result rows are either all new or all old, but not mixed.